# How to replace 0.x with .x in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a CSS minifier script for fun and I now want to create a function that removes any unnecessary `0.x` with only `.x`. So for example this string:

```
attribute:0.12% 10.123% 0.1%
```

Should turn into:

```
attribute:.12% 10.123% .1%
```

I tried to use a simple replace like this: `.replaceAll(':0.', ':.')` but this doesn't work for the case when the number stands alone like the `0.1%` does in my example.

I am not very good with regular expressions but I guess that is what I need. So basically I want to find all numbers that match the format `0.` but DON'T have a number immediately to the left of them (like in the case `10.123%`) and replace it with `.`.

Comment: why are you not running .replaceAll('0.', '.') meaning without the :

Comment: @PhilippM because that will change 10.123 into 1.123. Please see the example result

Comment: :D sorry my bad. You could use this .replaceAll(/(:|\s)0./gm, '$1.')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly this:

> So basically I want to find all numbers that match the format 0. but DON'T have a number immediately to the left of them (like in the case 10.123%) and replace it with

This pattern checks for a 0 followed by a dot (0.), but only if there isn't a digit immediately to the left of the 0.

```js
const input = 'attribute:0.12% 10.123% 0.1%';
const regex = /(?<!\d)0\./g;
const output = input.replace(regex, '.');

console.log(output); // attribute:.12% 10.123% .1%
```

Comment: Thank you, precicely what I needed! Any good source where I can learn these cryptic things from? :)

Comment: @eligolf If you want to learn js and regex try: https://www.freecodecamp.org/

It's interactive, very good described and fun to do!

Comment: *Any good source where I can learn these cryptic things from* - keeping to SO, the so [tag:regex] is a good place to start - links to the [regex SO wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) (via learn more...) which includes many resource and links to the [SO regex reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) which provides a fine reference - though possibly a little more than overwhelming - it is a reference page rather than a tutorial.

Comment: I also have no idea.  Answer is well formatted, quoting the issue and providing a snippet.   Sometimes people think they've answered in the comments so downvote (I've seen comments like "as I said 2 hours ago" referring to a comment) - but comments *are not answers*.